# modulus operation when one of the operand is negative value c++

Tags: c++, vector, modulus

I have a `vector<int> table` and an int `index=-833099133`

When I write

```
cout<<table.size()<<endl;
cout<< index%table.size()<<endl;
```

It gives me :

```
83
  81
```

however If I write

```
cout<<index%83<<endl;
```

output turns out:

```
-79
```

Is there anyone to help me why it occurs ? thanks in advance

Comment: `table.size()` is unsigned, `83` is an `int` which is signed... and then comes integer promotion, some black magic, and you got your results.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks for reply, could you write it as an answer I want to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.size()` is of type `std::vector<int>::size_type`, which is an **unsigned** type (usually `std::size_t`), but the literal `83` is an `int` which is signed.

When performing an operation on a signed and an unsigned integer, the signed one is implicitly converted ("promoted") to an unsigned value. That results in a non-negative number which is the original value modulo some power of two (which power is used depends on the width of the unsigned type). In your case, `size_t` was 32 bits long, so

```
-833099133 == 3461868163 (mod 2 ^ 32)
```

and of course, `3461868163 % 83` is 81, whereas `-833099133 % 83` is -79. (`-833099133 mod 83` would be +4, but in C++, the `%` is not the modulo, but the **remainder** operator.)

Indeed, if you run the following program on a system where `std::size_t` is 32 bits long:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int idx = -833099133;
    int signed83 = 83;
    std::size_t unsigned83 = 83;

    std::cout << idx % signed83 << std::endl;
    std::cout << idx % unsigned83 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

you will get the same results.